# How to add custom image to font awesome icon

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I'm a fan of [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) I'm using lots of icons from there. But, now I need adding my custom image to font awesome file for using as icon. I want to add them to font icons files so that I can use their property like `.fa-2x` `.fa-lg` etc By researching on internet I found that I can convert my svg image to font using [icomoon](http://icomoon.io/) or [font custom](http://fontcustom.com/) But, my confusion is after downloading files of my generating images as fonts how can I add those to font awesome files. I mean, there are already some files named

- FontAwesome (Open Type Font File)
- fontawesome-webfont.eot
- fontawesome-webfont (SVG Document)
- fontawesome-webfont (True Type Font File)
- fontawesome-webfont.woff

Should I've to put anything on those files after downloading my custom generated fonts files? Or, should I've to put the CSS code from custom generated fonts files to fontawesome.css? if this, what CSS code should I put on there? I ain't experienced so much with this process. So, I'm confused with this. That's why, I can't tell everything arranged way. Sorry for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best bet might be using a service like Fontello where you can "create" your own custom icon font and upload the custom icons there in addition to selecting the icons you need from Font Awesome.